# How can I decrease font size with conditional formatting when font size is not available?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am creating a sliding ruler in Google Sheets to convert one type of (fantastic) old coinage to others; think modern decimal counting to early Renaissance English currency. When getting large numbers, the cells become to small for the numbers to fit, so they get cut on the left and right side (centered adjustment). I would like to alleviate this by using `=len(f32)>3` for cell range F32:EF32, repeating for all other rows as necessary. However, I cannot find a way to set font size; only bold, italic, underline, and colour and background are available choices.

Is there a way to circumvent this, for example by setting conditional formatting to be equal to the formatting of a specified cell? Increasing cell size is not an option, nor is it an option to increase the number of merged cells.

Comment: How about the latter part of the question: Is there a way of circumventing it, such as by creating a cell with the desired formatting, and set formatting equal to that cell if conditions are met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, yet. Probably will be possible, eventually.

As you write in your Title *font size is not available*.